# how to Use Parse REST API to store an image to Parse with VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parse-platform

Guys I have a problem with register an image to Parse Dashboard using Vue Js (REST API), really I'm confused and I don't know how to do that;

At this moment, I'm using q-file to store the image to the front end then I've tried to follow [Parse REST Guid](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#files)

to store the image like:

1- my q-file template:

```
<q-file color="teal" filled v-model="image" label="L'image du véhicule">
   <template v-slot:prepend>
      <q-icon name="cloud_upload"/>
  </template>
</q-file>
```

2- the response of image variable is:

```
lastModified: 1602270533393
lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 09 2020 20:08:53 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) {}
name: "hero.png"
size: 1943796
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

3- then I'm using this service to fire the storing:

```
UserDataService.storeImage(this.image)
```

and the storeImage function:

```
async storeImage(image) {
    console.log(image.name)
    console.log(image)
    await axios.post('/parse/image/image', open(image.name, 'rb').read())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        Notify.create({ message: 'Erreur de connexion', position: 'bottom-right' })
      })
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem that you have with the current code?

Comment: I need to create a new object with image column in Parse class and I don't know haw to do that

Comment: Have you tried the endpoints in this link? https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#files